# join three tables with count and sum in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have three tables and trying to join these tables with count(working_days) and sum(Overtime) functions but overtime is not showing correct i am trying the query is.

```
SELECT E.EMP_CODE,E.EMP_NAME,
COALESCE(SUM(O.OVERTIME),0) AS OVERTIME,COALESCE(COUNT(C.EMP_ATT),0) WORKED_DAYS
FROM EMP E
LEFT JOIN OVERTIME   O
ON E.EMP_CODE = O.EMP_CODE
LEFT JOIN ATT_REG C
ON E.EMP_CODE=C.EMP_CODE
GROUP BY E.EMP_CODE,E.EMP_NAME 
ORDER BY EMP_CODE
```

Comment: At least, provide the data model of the tables involved in the query, and explain why the result is not ok. Which result ?? Why is not correct ??

Comment: I get wrong values of overtime.Overtime multiplying with worked_day.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You will get multiple records of the overtime for employees as shift date (or similar in your table) is missing in the join.

```
SELECT E.EMP_CODE,E.EMP_NAME,
COALESCE(SUM(O.OVERTIME),0) AS OVERTIME,
COALESCE(COUNT(C.EMP_ATT),0) WORKED_DAYS
FROM EMP E
LEFT JOIN ATT_REG C
ON E.EMP_CODE=C.EMP_CODE
LEFT JOIN OVERTIME   O
ON E.EMP_CODE = O.EMP_CODE 
AND C.SHIFTDATE = O.SHIFDATE -- YOU NEED SOMETHING LIKE THIS
GROUP BY E.EMP_CODE,E.EMP_NAME 
ORDER BY EMP_CODE
```